# Javascript countdown and Timezones

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdoaw.jpg)
basically I insert a row with a datetime + interval (something in the future) with a SQL query.

```
    $interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$H.'H'.$i.'M'.$s.'S');
    $date = new DateTime(); $date->add($interval);
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles_in_missions (id_pim, id_profile, id_mission, time) VALUES (NULL, :idprofile, :idmission,:time)");
    $query->bindValue(':idprofile', $tableau[0]);
    $query->bindValue(':idmission', $id);
    $query->bindValue(':time', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $query->execute();
```

If my pc shows: 23:40, and if i insert DateTime with interval of +8minutes, this query will store 21:48 in the database. Till now okay,  my database is GTM+00 and my pc default browser is GTM+2.

Once stored, i am trying to pick this date who got (in that case) -2h+8m and and make a countdown.

*Now the problem:* To make the countdown, i am using javascript and i do 21:48-now(); BUT he will always end 2h faster than normal, because the stored date (21:48) in MYSQL with GTM+00 BUT Javascript now(); is getting my default browser time GTM+2.

Is there a way to make Javascript work with server Timezone GTM+00? How can i fix my problem? There is all my code for the countdown:

```
<script>

var t = document.getElementById('myInputTimer').value;
var countDownDate = new Date(t).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date().getTime()` (which can be replaced with `Date.now()`) simply returns the number of milliseconds from date zero. Timezone isn't a factor here, where timezone becomes a factor is here:

```
var t = document.getElementById('myInputTimer').value;
var countDownDate = new Date(t).getTime();
```

If the string you use to create the date object doesn't contain any timezone information, it assumes the timezone of the browser.
I'm assuming this string is the date you have in UTC time?

One solution is to make sure this string contains timezone information, which means it would look like this: `2017-06-03T22:23:00+00:00`

Another solution is to correct for the timezone offset after you've parsed the date. So if `new Date("2017-06-03 22:23:00")` gives you `Sat Jun 03 2017 22:23:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` which is 20:23 you can correct it by subtracting the timezone offset:

```
var countDownDate = new Date(t).getTime() - (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```

`.getTimezoneOffset()` returns the timezone offset in minutes, we calculate how many milliseconds it is and then subtract it from the milliseconds returned by `.getTime()`

Using a string to create a date isn't the best idea however since it's implementation dependent and unreliable. It's better to parse out the various components (year, month, day, hours, and so on) and construct the date with those. You can use a regexp to parse out the components like this:

```
var dateParts = t.match(/\d+/g);
```

And the best part is that now you can use `Date.UTC()` instead of `new Date(t).getTime()` to get the time in UTC directly:

```
var countDownDate = Date.UTC.apply(null, dateParts);
```

Comment: **Man I just want to kiss you right now !** Thanks you so much. Thank you so much for the time you spend with that anwser. He worked 100%